# Bootstrap 5 form-select show multiple but only allow to select one

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I want to build a modal with a list of options whereas only one should be select-able. However, the basic form-select is a dropdown menu with an unnecessary click I want to avoid. Instead it should just display all options like with the multiple attribute. However, the user shouldn't be able to select more than one item.

```
<select class="form-select">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

The solution above has the correct behavior.

```
<select multiple class="form-select">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

The solution above has the correct aesthetics.

Is there a way to combine both?

Comment: @j08691 thank you for the advice, leaving out bootstrap in the search brought the solution. Apparently setting the size is enough to create the desired behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it has nothing to do with bootstrap. The "size" attribute can be used to expand the selection list.

```
<select class="form-select" size=2>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```